# Creating a new directory in C [linux]

Tags: c, linux, directory

I'm trying to create new directory and inside new file, i tried open() with a lot of variations but no success.

```
open("Folder/file.txt", O_CREAT);
```

tried also with O_DIRECTORY..

I've not found any thread that has a proper solution.

- I can't use mkdir, i'm allowed to use only system calls for file management

Comment: `mkdir`, is a system call, `man 2 mkdir`. If you want to see what syscalls are made on a utility, run `strace <exe>`, and see what it says.

Comment: Anyway there's a way to do it with open?

Comment: @eli99 it can't be done with open. Roughly: the system call for creating a directory _is_  `mkdir`, just like the system call for opening a file is `open`.